# Flutter: Sharing Image and text both from app to WhatsApp(ios)

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to share an image and a text from my Flutter app using the below code:

`Share.shareFiles([saveImage.path], text: 'www.google.com');`

`This code works well when testing on Android devices` - The image and the text are sent to WhatsApp as expected. However, when `tested on iOS, it only sends text and no image`. When I comment out the text, the image gets shared. But that does not serve my purpose, I need both the image and text sent together.

I have tried with both the plugins : '[share](https://pub.dev/packages/share)' & '[share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)', same issue.

I have tried to circumvent this problem but I haven't been very successful. Every time, it is either only the image or the text that gets shared.

I also understand from this [thread](https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/issues/36#issuecomment-656122936) (and a few others similar to it), that this is not an issue with the plugins or Flutter, but has something to do with the WhatsApp API - while no workaround is shared anywhere.

But I need this working, there is no way to either send only image or only text (url). I am down to the point where I'm thinking of either splitting it up into two separate messages or simply stop depending on the plugins itself. Both of which are a messy solution.

It is a very common feature to develop for isn't it? - every app will have some social sharing mechanism to increase the download count. So, how is everybody else getting this done (for iOS devices)? Some other plugin maybe?

Some help please.

Comment: I also had this issue, due to an issue in the whatsapp API for iOS. This indeed isn't working. We deceided to only share the image and add the text later when the API and plugin get updated.